# Improper accuracy after graph restore

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I've trained a basic CNN on mnist data and has a validation score of around 95% before saving the model after 5 iterations

Now my intention is to import saved graph (instead writing again) and restore the parameters from the saved model.

All looks good, but when I tried to test the validation accuracy on the restored graph, results doesn't seem to be right. Where am I going wrong?

**original model**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data",one_hot=True)


with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784], name='xs')
    ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10], name='ys')
    keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')

x_image = tf.reshape(xs,[-1,28,28,1])

with tf.variable_scope('conv1',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    W_conv1 = tf.get_variable('weights',dtype=tf.float32, shape=[5,5,1,32], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0,stddev=0.1))
    b_conv1 = tf.get_variable('bias', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[32],initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.1))
    h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(x_image, W_conv1, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME') + b_conv1,name='conv')
    h_pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv1, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding = 'SAME',name='max_pool')

with tf.variable_scope('conv2',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    W_conv2 = tf.get_variable('weights',dtype=tf.float32, shape=[5,5,32,64], initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0,stddev=0.1))
    b_conv2 = tf.get_variable('bias', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[64],initializer=tf.constant_initializer(value=0.1))
    h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding='SAME') + b_conv2,name='conv')
    h_pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(h_conv2, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding = 'SAME',name='max_pool')
    h_pool2_flatten = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])

with tf.variable_scope('FCLayer_1', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    Weights_1 = tf.get_variable('weights', dtype = tf.float32, shape=[7*7*64, 1024] , initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0,stddev=0.1))
    Bias_1 = tf.get_variable('bias', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[1024],initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    WxPlusB_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flatten,Weights_1), Bias_1),name='WxPlusB')
    output_1 = tf.nn.dropout(WxPlusB_1, name='dropouts', keep_prob=keep_prob)
    tf.summary.histogram('FCLayer_1/weights',Weights_1)



with tf.variable_scope('FCLayer_2', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    Weights_2 = tf.get_variable('weights', dtype = tf.float32, shape=[1024, 10] , 
                                initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(mean=0.0,stddev=0.1))

    Bias_2 = tf.get_variable('bias', dtype=tf.float32, shape=[10],initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.1))
    predictions = tf.nn.softmax(tf.add(tf.matmul(output_1,Weights_2), Bias_2),name='WxPlusB')
    tf.summary.histogram('Weights',Weights_2)


with tf.name_scope('accuracy'):
    accuarcy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(predictions,axis=1), tf.argmax(ys,axis=1)),dtype=tf.float32), name='accuracy')
    tf.summary.scalar(tensor=accuarcy,name='accuracy')

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum( ys * tf.log(predictions) , axis=1),name='cross_entropy')
    tf.summary.scalar(tensor=cross_entropy,name='cross_entropy')

with tf.variable_scope('optimizer',reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(epsilon=1e-4,beta1=0.9,beta2=0.99,name='optimizer')

with tf.variable_scope('train', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    train = optimizer.minimize(cross_entropy)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

saver = tf.train.Saver()



with tf.Session() as sess:

    try:
        saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('cnn_model'))

    except Exception as err:
        sess.run(init)

    train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./cnnlogs/train/',graph=sess.graph)
    test_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./cnnlogs/test', graph=sess.graph)
    merge_all = tf.summary.merge_all()

    for i in range(50):
        train_x, train_y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
        sess.run(train,feed_dict={xs: train_x, ys : train_y, keep_prob : 0.5})
        if i % 10 == 0:

            train_result,train_accuarcy,train_loss = sess.run([merge_all, accuarcy, cross_entropy],
                                                        feed_dict = { xs : train_x, 
                                                                      ys : train_y,
                                                                      keep_prob : 1.0
                                                                    })
            test_result,test_accuarcy,test_loss = sess.run([merge_all, accuarcy, cross_entropy],
                                                        feed_dict = { xs : mnist.validation.images, 
                                                                      ys : mnist.validation.labels,
                                                                      keep_prob : 1.0
                                                                    })
            train_writer.add_summary(summary=train_result, global_step = i)
            test_writer.add_summary(summary=test_result, global_step = i)

            print('Train Accuracy: {} Train Loss: {} Test Accuracy: {} Test Loss: {}'.format(train_accuarcy,
                                                                                             train_loss,
                                                                                             test_accuarcy,
                                                                                            test_loss))

    saver.save(sess,'cnn_model/model.ckpt')
```

**Results**

```
Train Accuracy: 0.23999999463558197 Train Loss: 7.2988080978393555 **Test Accuracy: 0.1907999962568283** Test Loss: 8.40633773803711
Train Accuracy: 0.6299999952316284 Train Loss: 1.0147693157196045 **Test Accuracy: 0.6912000179290771** Test Loss: 1.028536081314087
Train Accuracy: 0.8399999737739563 Train Loss: 0.5975856184959412 **Test Accuracy: 0.8307999968528748** Test Loss: 0.6595735549926758
Train Accuracy: 0.8700000047683716 Train Loss: 0.36984387040138245 **Test Accuracy: 0.8795999884605408** Test Loss: 0.4149101674556732
Train Accuracy: 0.8299999833106995 Train Loss: 0.5599954128265381 **Test Accuracy: 0.9016000032424927** Test Loss: 0.320442616939544
```

**Restored Model**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data",one_hot=True)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # resorte the model
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('cnn_model/model.ckpt.meta')
    # resotre the lastest params into model
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('cnn_model'))

    graph = tf.get_default_graph()

    xs = graph.get_tensor_by_name('inputs/xs:0')

    ys = graph.get_tensor_by_name('inputs/ys:0')


    Weights_1 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('FCLayer_1/weights:0')
    Weights_2 = graph.get_tensor_by_name('FCLayer_2/weights:0')

    keep_prob = graph.get_tensor_by_name('inputs/keep_prob:0')

    accuracy = graph.get_tensor_by_name('accuracy/accuracy:0')
    cross_entropy = graph.get_tensor_by_name('loss/cross_entropy:0')

    test_accuracy , test_loss = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy], 
                                        feed_dict={xs : mnist.validation.images,
                                                   ys : mnist.validation.labels,
                                                   keep_prob : 1.0})

    print(test_accuracy)
```

**Results**

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from cnn_model\model.ckpt
Test_accuracy: 0.1126   << Not Right
```

However if I tried to restore params from the original model itself things seems to work. I'm able to get accuracy > 90% and continue training from where I left last time

I've checked the weights and biases in the restored model and seems to be inline to that of the original model. However accuracy, cross_entropies are going for a toss post restoration.

Comment: Which TensorFlow version? I ran the save followed by the restore; after 100 iterations the test accuracy was ` 0.9448000...` before export, and running the import snippet in a new Python program I get `0.9448`. (FWIW this is running on the nightly 1.13.0-dev20181019)

Comment: My version of tensorflow is '1.9.0'.

Comment: Hrm. Just tried it with 1.9.0. The last test accuracy (50 iterations) was `0.933000028133`, the import script prints `0.933`.